# Problemas ao acessar um site via RStudio

Tags: aplicação-web, r, scraping

Problemas ao conectar há um determinado site via RStudio

```
 url <- "https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/diarios/busca?q=%22licen%C3%A7a+sem+vencimentos%22&idtopico=T10001849&o=data"
links <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes('.DocumentSnippet') %>% html_nodes('a')
```

Gerando o seguinte erro:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Failed to connect to www.jusbrasil.com.br port 443: Connection refused
```

Acredito que seja a configuração do proxy no RStudio (ou no próprio R). Tentei as soluções abaixo, mas sempre houve o mesmo erro:

1. [Configuring R to Use an HTTP or HTTPS Proxy](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-Proxy)
2. O código `set_config(use_proxy(url = "meuproxy", port = "meuproxy", user="user" e password = "password"))`. Com o proxy e meu login e senha da rede.

Sei que o código funciona, pois testei no meu computador doméstico e consegui os links esperados.

Comment: Você tentou fazer algo deste tipo? `GET("http://had.co.nz", use_proxy("64.251.21.73", 8080), verbose())`

Comment: Com o site que você passou funciona normal, mas ao tentar algo simples como:
`t1 <- GET("http://had.co.nz/",
          use_proxy("10.10.120.59", 80, "flavio.matos", "password"), verbose())

links <- read_html(t1) %>% html_text()`
O resultado é `"Notificação: Autorização de proxy necessária(...)`. Já quando tento o mesmo código para o site que preciso tenho o seguinte problema: 

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT`

Comment: @FlavioSilva esse problema está associado a sua configuração de proxy sim. Por favor, qual é seu sistema operacional e versão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acesse esse site antes: https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/robots.txt lá tem as definições do que você pode ou não acessar.

Robots.txt: https://rockcontent.com/br/blog/robots-txt/

Essa resposta pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690914/web-scraping-the-iis-based-website